# Tests fail in Jenkins

Tags: java, resources, maven, junit, jenkins

I have a maven project which is build and tested in Jenkins. On my local machine the tests run successful but in Jenkins a file cannot be loaded which is needed by the test. I use `this.getClass.getResourceAsStream("testfile.dat")` to load the resource. It seems that Jenkins doesn't copy the resource files to the directory the tests are running in. Is that a maven problem? How do I advice Jenkins/Maven to copy the resources to the test classpath?

Comment: Where do they need to be copied from?  Are they in `src/test/resources` like they are supposed to be?

Comment: They were in `src/test/resources/my/package`. Now I have moved them to `src/test/resources` and changed my test class to `this.getClass.getResourceAsStream("/testfile.dat")`. Now the files are found. So I think you solved my problem. If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put your test resources in the `src/test/resources` *tree* of your Maven project.  Maven will ensure that they are on the classpath when your tests are run, and hence that they can be found using `getResourceAsStream(...)`.

Comment: In my experience there is no problem with having sub-directories below the standard resources folder, Maven copies them all over. I also think that it's good practice to group resources by package.

Comment: @Waldheinz - I didn't mean to imply that there WAS a problem!

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `getResourceAsStream` with a string argument which does not specify a package (as in your example "testfile.dat"), the resource must be located in exactly the same package (aka folder) as the `Class` object you are calling the `getResourceAsStream` method on. You should check if both, the class and it's resources are really in the same package.

You might want to have a look at the `target` folder Maven generates when packaging your project, you can find out where your resources end up there.

Comment: Ummm ... we are talking about a TEST resource.  It shouldn't end up in the artifacts generated by the packager ... or in the target folder.

Comment: @Stephen C But all I said still applies, just that it's not below the "main" but the "test" folder (and you have to look in `target/test-classes` instead of `target/classes`).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but I did not want to move the resources to src/test/resources for various reasons.
Nevertheless I could solve the problem by adding explicitly all subfolders to the pom.xml as the following snippet shows:

```
<build>
  <resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>myFolder/subFolder1</directory>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>myFolder/subFolder2</directory>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>myFolder/subFolder3</directory>
    </resource>
  </resources>
    [....]
</build>
```